# Bash: Loop through all subsubdirectories and execute command on certain files

Tags: bash, shell-script, latex

My folder structure looks like this

```
Main
├── Sub1
|   ├── Subsub1
|   |   |   ├── file1.tex
|   |   |   ├── file2.tex
|   ├── Subsub2
|   |   |   ├── file1.tex
|   |   |   ├── file2.tex
├── Sub2
|   ├── Subsub1
|   |   |   ├── file1.tex
|   |   |   ├── file2.tex
|   ├── Subsub2
|   |   |   ├── file1.tex
|   |   |   ├── file2.tex
```

I want to loop to all subsubdirectories and execute the command `pdflatex` on each file.

**My try**

```
for d in */*/ ; do
    pdflatex "$d*.tex"
done
```

...but this doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you tell us _in what way_ it doesn't work? Is there any console output you can share with us that may help understand the problem? If so, please edit your question to include the relevant information.

Comment: Try removing `"` from pdflatex like that `pdflatex $d*.tex`. This will call pdflatex for each directory with all `*.tex` files. That means pdflatex will get called four times for the structure shown in your answer. Each time with two files as parameter. If you want to have pdflatex called eight times. It has to be done differently.

Comment: Also can you use a better variable name, it will help us see your intentions. Should `d` be `directory_name` or `file_name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you use `globstar` shell option.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar

for d in Main/**/*.tex; do
  echo pdflatex "$d"
done
```

Or use find.

```
find Main/ -type f -name '*.tex' -exec sh -c 'echo pdflatex  "$@"' _ {} +
```

Remove the echo once you're satisfied with the result.

Comment: How to move the current directory always to the directory where the current file is?

Comment: move the current directory?

Comment: The ´pdflatex´ command only works if the current working directory is where the file is (because I have some relative path in my .tex files).

Comment: How to set the current working directory to the directory of my .tex file in the loop? [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349105/how-to-set-current-working-directory-to-the-directory-of-the-script)

Comment: I have updated the answer. pleas take a look.

Comment: I've just posted a [new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568892/bash-how-to-set-the-current-working-directory-to-the-current-directory-in-a-loo).

Comment: Your updated answer results in `I can't find the file Main/**/*.tex.`

Comment: `Main`  is the directory that you gave in your example directory structure.

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work. For your information: The bash script is in the Main directory and from there I call it.

Comment: [This is the solution to my question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568896/396586) Thanks @Jetchisel.